# use file content to create a nested list in python

Tags: python, list, parsing, nested-lists

I have a text file sample.txt(space delimited) in this format

```
12 john E 44 L
13 adam D 78 L
14 tue E 98 L
```

I want to to convert this file into a nested list

```
table_data = [
        [12, 'john', 'E', 44, 'L'],
        [13, 'adam', 'D', 78, 'L'],
        [14, 'tue', 'E', 98, 'L'],
]
```

How can i do it ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `str.split` and a list comprehension:

```
with open('filename') as f:
   table_data = [ line.split() for line in f]
```

If you want the numbers to be converted to integers then write an additional function that processes each item on a give line:

```
def func(x):
    try:                                                         
        return int(x)
    except ValueError:
        return x
>>> with open('abc1') as f:
...     table_data = [[ func(x) for x in line.split()] for line in f]
...     
>>> table_data
[[12, 'john', 'E', 44, 'L'],
 [13, 'adam', 'D', 78, 'L'],
 [14, 'tue', 'E', 98, 'L']]
```

Comment: `map(func,line.split())` would be nicer

Comment: @HennyH Some people hate `map`, so I prefer a LC. :/

Answer (score 1):

Use the inbuilt [`csv` package](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html)

```
from csv import reader

types = [int, str, str, int, str]

with open('sample.txt', 'rb') as f:
    table_data = [[t(v) for v, t in zip(row, types)] for row in reader(f, delimiter=' ')]
print table_data
```

Has the output:

```
[[12, 'john', 'E', 44, 'L'], [13, 'adam', 'D', 78, 'L'], [14, 'tue', 'E', 98, 'L']]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a = '''12 john E 44 L
13 adam D 78 L
14 tue E 98 L'''

table_data = [b.split(' ') for b in a.split('\n')]
print table_data
```

Where table_data is:

```
table_data = [['12', 'john', 'E', '44', 'L'],
              ['13', 'adam', 'D', '78', 'L'],
              ['14', 'tue', 'E', '98', 'L']]
```